# Insert Data in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="10.0.72.17",
  user="admin",
  passwd="1qaz!QAZ",
  database="test"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


sql = "INSERT INTO biage(kompaniis_saxeli) VALUES (%s)"
val = ('bane')
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mydb.commit()
```

This is my python code , and i create `column`

```
kompaniis_saxeli varchar(225)
```

but when i try to run this code there is error

```
 raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

Comment: In Python, `('bane')` is the same as `'bane'`, thus you're providing a string. You need to provide a tuple as the argument, and if you have only one value to pass, you can use `val = ('bane',)` (note the comma after the first element).

Answer (score 2):

The python driver needs at least a 2 dimensional list for values

So use:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="10.0.72.17",
  user="admin",
  passwd="1qaz!QAZ",
  database="test"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


sql = "INSERT INTO biage(kompaniis_saxeli) VALUES (%s)"
val = ('bane',)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mydb.commit()
```